# Why these two middleware gets called twice even for a single GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, server

I wrote two simple middlewares using Express and put a log inside both of them and also passed the control from one middleware to the next middleware using next() function but when I run the app.js file using npm start ( inside package.json -> "start" : "nodemon app.js" ), the logs are printed twice and not once and I can't seem to understand why this happened.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In the middleware!');
    next(); // Allows the request to continue to the next middleware in line
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('In another middleware!');
    res.send('<h1>Hello from Express!</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The output I got when running localhost:3000 is:

```
In the middleware!
In another middleware!
In the middleware!
In another middleware!
```

Even though I just clicked the link(reload) once.

Comment: I'd assume that the second call is the browser asking for `favicon.ico`. Can you please print the requested path using `console.log(req.path)` to verify this?

Comment: I've been try your code and it's working fine.

Comment: @GoloRoden Thanks for this. Such a naive mistake, yes the other request is made for /favicon.io and thus why the middleware is called twice.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)